# Topological Connectedness $\implies$ Order Completeness

Tags: ordered-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an arbitrary ordered field. We define:

1. $\textbf{Topological Connectedness:}$
   If $\mathbb{F}=A \cup B$ where A,B are nonempty and open, then $A \cap B \neq \phi$.
2. $\textbf{Order Completeness :}$
   If $S \subset \mathbb{F}$ is bounded above, then $\exists \ c \in \mathbb{F}$ that is an upperbound of S and for every upperbound $b$ of S, we have $c \leq b.$
3. **Cut Property:** If $A,B \subset \mathbb{F} \ (A \cap B = \phi \ , \ A \cup B=\mathbb{F} \ , \ A<B)$, then
   $\exists \ c \in \mathbb{F} \ (x \in A \implies x \leq c,
                \ x \in B \implies c \leq x)$ 
   By $A<B$, I mean every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$.

It can be shown that **2. $\iff$ 3.** So we proceed as follows,

"$\implies$" 
We prove the contrapositive by the way of Cut Property.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets satisfying the hypothesis of the Cut Property but violating its conclusion.
There exists no $c$ such that everything less than $c$ is in $A$ and everything greater than $c$ is in $B$.

Then for every $a \in A$ there exists $a' \in A$ with $a < a'$. And for every $b \in B$ there exists
$b' \in B$ with $b' < b$.
(How?, by choosing $c=max(A)$ or $max(B)$).

Using this it can be shown that both $A$ and $B$ are open(How?, by choosing $\epsilon=a'-a$), that contradicts the topological
connectivity of $\mathbb{F}$.

**My question: Is the converse true?**

Comment: For ordered fields, we have order completeness $\Longrightarrow$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. So all properties of $\mathbb{R}$ are a consequence of order completeness.

Comment: You mean isomorphic as a field right?

Comment: In $\mathbb{F}$ Colection of all open intervals forms a basis for a topology. Can we tell that $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: They are isomorphic for any structure which is defined (first order or not) starting from the structure of ordered fields, which is arguably all one ever uses with $\mathbb{R}$. They are isomorphic as measurable spaces, topological spaces, affine spaces and so on.